# The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version even if I add AllowLoadLocalInfile

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mysql-connector

I am trying to use the mysql bulkloader class and I receive the following error even if I add AllowLoadLocalInfile=true to my connection string.

Error: `The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version e`

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str1);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;database=testDB;uid=testUser;pwd=pass;AllowLoadLocalInfile=true;"))
{
    MySqlBulkLoader bcp1 = new MySqlBulkLoader(mConnection);
    bcp1.SourceStream = stream;
    bcp1.TableName = "TableA";
    bcp1.FieldTerminator = ",";
    bcp1.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
    bcp1.Local = true;

    mConnection.Open();

    bcp1.Load();
}
```

Does anyone knows why am I getting this?

Comment: Why didn't you post also what is in str1?

Comment: a csv file parsed into string

Comment: What's your MySQL Server and version? Are you using MySql.Data or MySqlConnector? Which version?

Comment: MySql Server 8, MySqlConnector 0.56.0.0 using EF Core with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure the [`local-infile`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile) MySQL Server variable is set to `ON`. By default, in MySQL Server 8.0.2 or later, it's `OFF`, which disables `LOAD DATA LOCAL` from any client; this [is a security feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local.html).

Comment: Thank you. for those that don't know how to do this please see the following link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48751/enabling-load-data-local-infile-in-mysql